# Laptop unable to shut down

Tags: laptop, battery, shutdown, dell-inspiron

I had a process that I couldn't end (which is a trusted process), so I decided to restart my PC, now both the coolers (fans) and the keyboard lighting is working while monitor is black. The mouse seems to be not powered (no laser).

But the machine won't shut down completely and it's been like this for 3 hours (while it's battery usually lasts around 1.5h).

I have no access to it's battery, because I don't have the right screwdriver and at the moment it's too late (11pm) to buy one. I've been able to charge my phone from it via USB by 10% over 3 hours.

**Is there any other way to force shut down except for removing/discharging the battery completely?**

*The power button is not responsive.*

The laptop is a Dell Inspiron 7559

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not reproducible.  OP comment on the answer indicates that the problem went away after the battery discharged.

Answer (score 1):

Press and hold the power button for 10 seconds. This will shut the computer down entirely unless there is an actual hardware fault.

Comment: Lol mate, thats a great advice, since that was the 1st thing i did to try and stop this, anyway, its discharged and working again, thread closed

Comment: Your question stated the power button is not responsive, but it does not specify what it is not responsive to. There is a difference between briefly "clicking" the power button and press-and-holding the power button for 10 seconds. There have only been a VERY small handful of times that holding the power button did not close the system down because that signal is generally sent at the hardware level, which is outside of the OS and bypasses entirely any trusted applications.